# Pair sum algorithm - performance with binary search

Tags: algorithm, scala, performance, sum

I am implementing an algorithm with Scala for finding values x1 and x2 from separate arrays l1 and l2 such that x1 + x2 = t, where t is some target value.

Algorithm 1 iterates through l1 and l2 one by one and checks if x1+x2=t. Runs in O(n^2). 
Algorithm 2 sorts l2, then performs a binary search on it for each item in l1. Supposedly runs in O(nlogn) but does not. Why is it running slower than algorithm 1?

Note that this is a course assignment, i'm looking for clues only.

Algorithm 1:

```
def hasPairSlow(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int], target: Int): Option[Pair[Int,         Int]] = {
  l1 foreach { i => 
    l2 foreach { j => if (i+j == target) return Some(i -> j) } 
  }
  None
}
```

Algorithm 2:

```
def hasPair(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int], target: Int): Option[Pair[Int, Int]]   = {
  val s2 = l2.sorted
  l1 foreach { i =>
    val p = checkPair(i, s2, target)
    if (p.isDefined) return Some(i, p.get)
  }
  None
}

private def checkPair(x: Int, l: List[Int], target: Int): Option[Int] = {
  val mid = l.length / 2
  if (mid == 0) { // Length == 1
    if (l.head + x == target) Some(l.head) else None
  } else {
    val candinate = l(mid)
    if (candinate + x == target) Some(candinate)
    else {
      val s = l.splitAt(mid)
      if (candinate + x > target) {
        checkPair(x, s._1, target)
      }
      else /* candinate + x < target */ {
        checkPair(x, s._2, target)
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Well... first of all... `List` in scala is a `LinkedList`. Which means finding `mth` element in a `List` takes `O(m)` time. Which means every thing like `val candinate = l(mid)` is actually `O(mid)` and not `C` .And this fact is one of the most obvious candidates for the problem in your algorithm. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: Start from starting of L1 and end of L2 and follow similar approach you would follow when you need to find sum with only single array.

Comment: You can choose `Vector` or `Range` instead of list as these have random access time complexity in `Asymptotically constant` and `Constant` time respectively. Try this with `Range` which gives you `constant` time random access and then we can talk about other problems.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh , Thanks for the tip. I'll try both and see how it affects perfomance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val s = l.splitAt(mid)
```

The `splitAt` function traverses the entire list (as does random access in a List), so your second algorithm is no better. It is worse because of the overhead involved in element accesses and list splitting.

Comment: Thanks, converting the List to a Vector before performing the binary search did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I can't comment due to low reputation, but I'm curious to what you mean by "runs slower"? The complexity for both algorithms are given in worst case. Even with very large n, it would be perfectly possible for Alg1 to outpreform Alg2 in terms of time (such as finding the answer on the first iteration).

Comment: The assignment came with a file which simply runs both algorithms for n > 10000 and prints the time. You're right, i could have been more clear with that.